# Passing PHP array to CakePHP's form helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, form-helpers

I've sent arrays to CakePHP like this in the past:

`$this->Form->input("Req.{$i}");`

I've manually put `{$i}` in which is derived from the code itself in a loop. Ideally I wanted to put in something like `Req.{}` to generate the next key index, but it seemed only manually putting it in would work. Years later I need to have something like

`$this->Form->input("Req.{$i}.list.{}");`

And I'd like to avoid generating an `{$i2}`. Basically, I'm asking how to properly send multi-dimensional arrays to `$this->request->data` on POST, without having to specify an index name, much like we might have `<input name='whatever[]'>` in traditional PHP. I'm posting with jQuery AJAX, if that matters.

**Update:**
Following drmonkeyninja's answer, I received

```
[list] => Array(
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [req] => 
                                )
                 )
```

It seems it will be required that I make an $i2 as PHP/HTML have no way of knowing that I'm *not* trying to make a new array for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in CakePHP you define the array path separating array indexes using `.`:-

```
$this->Form->input('Model.0.value'); // name="data[Model][0][value]"
```

If you don't want to specify a numerical index you can just use `..` to represent an empty index:-

```
$this->Form->input('Model..value'); // name="data[Model][][value]"
```

**Update**

If you can't get the CakePHP array path syntax working in the way you need you can always manually set the input names in the `input` options:-

```
$this->Form->input('Model..value', ['name' => 'data[Model][][value]']);
```

Comment: I thought so too, but I get this when I try with more than one sub-dimensional key, let's say I have name and value: 
[list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 'x' ) [1] => Array ([value] => 'y' ). Maybe it's just impossible for CakePHP to determine that I don't want to create two NEW arrays, but rather that I want both name and value in the same array.

Comment: As an alternative you could manually set the input's name. See my updated answer.

Comment: Your reply was helpful in that it made me realize there's no solution for this without a `$i2`. I put the name as you have there, but I get `[0] => ('value' => 'x'), [1] => ('name' => 'y')` because PHP still thinks I'm making a new array for each [] it finds in the input name. I appreciate the help, I've updated my question.